# Android Navigation Architecture Component - Programmatically

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, navigation

Looking for examples or anything similar that takes Swift (iOS) code like this:

```
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initialView)
```

and sets it up in Kotlin, via the new Navigation component.  I've referenced the following examples, but it's not making complete sense to me:

```
val myNavHostController: NavHostFragment = nav_host_fragment as NavHostFragment
val inflater = myNavHostController.navController.navInflator
val graph = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_graph)
myNavHostController.navController.graph = graph
```

and

```
val finalHost = NavHostFragment.create(R.navigation.example_graph)
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.nav_host, finalHost)
    .setPrimaryNavigationFragment(finalHost) // this is the equivalent to app:defaultNavHost="true"
    .commit()
```

It appears the Android examples I'm coming across, still require an Activity/Fragment to already be established in the XML file created by the navigation component ... but, what if I want this functionality to be dynamic?  What if I need to set the 'host' activity for the nav component based on data passed in?  I am in need of the ability to do this all via code, which is what the Swift line is doing (setting the 'initialView' UIViewController, as the 'host', which has the navigation controller embedded in it).  None of it is done via storyboarding, which seems to be what Android wants me to do regardless...

I am certain the issue is me not fully understanding how this works in Android, which is what I really would like to learn.

Comment: Android builds around activities. You need at least one to have an app. But you can change the contentview in that activity, and use fragments, and effectively switch between layouts with a single activity. Changing the content view is a bad idea though, if you don't use fragments (considering memory management)

Comment: Now this makes sense and does align with where my internal thoughts were going...  

So, based on this, perhaps I need to set the initial 'host' as the mainActivity (which I already do have) and then change it if necessary?  This seems like it would work for what I'm trying to accomplish.  

I also agree with the fragment suggestions, which is why I plan to use the activity as the primary 'host', but branch everything off to fragments from there.

Hopefully I'm making sense...

Comment: (and if you want to be able to control your application state yourself, then you should have a maximum of one activity in your app)